# Prove that the tangent plane of S is well-defined independently of regular parametrization

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Hello StackExchange community,

I've been trying to prove Marsden and Tromba's Vector Calculus 5/E Exercise 7.3.17 part (c), which reads:

> Prove that the tangent plane of surface S is well-defined
> independently of the regular (one-to-one) parametrization, namely
> Φ(u,v) and Ψ(s(u,v),t(u,v)), using the inverse function theorem.

The two normal vectors Tu x Tv and Ts x Tt are supposed to be scalar multiples of each other, by a factor of the Jacobian determinant between the two sets of variables (u,v) and (s,t) but I can't seem to find a way to match the Jacobian.

$$
\dfrac{\partial \Phi}{\partial u} = \dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial u}
+\dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial u}
$$

and

$$
\dfrac{\partial \Phi}{\partial v} = \dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial v}
+\dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial v}
$$

So that

$$
\mathbf{T_u^\Phi} \times \mathbf{T_v^\Phi} = 
\dfrac{\partial \Phi}{\partial u} \mathbf i \times \dfrac{\partial \Phi}{\partial v} \mathbf j
= \left( \dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial u}
+\dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial u} \right) \cdot 
\left( \dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial s}\dfrac{\partial s}{\partial v}
+\dfrac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial v} \right) \mathbf k
$$

but I'm supposed to show that

$$
\mathbf{T_u^\Phi} \times \mathbf{T_v^\Phi} = \left( \dfrac{\partial{(s,t)}}{\partial{(u,v)}} \right) (\mathbf{T_s^\Psi} \times \mathbf{T_t^\Psi})
$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Edit your question to include the details of your calculation. In particular, give the chain rule explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have it updated now.

Comment: Perfect start. Remember that both $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ are vector functions. So just write out $\partial\Psi/\partial u\times\partial\Psi/\partial v$ using properties of $\times$.